# Sum of $2024$ variables in $[-2;3]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

Let's consider $2024$ variables $x_i$ that are arbitrary reals in $[-2;3]$ such that $x_1+x_2+...+x_{2024}=500$.
What is the greatest value of :
$$x_1^4+x_2^4+...+x_{2024}^4$$

Here is my approach but it is not rigorous. I wanted to choose the $x_i$ with extreme values. I wanted to take $167$ times a $3$ and $2$ times a $-0,5$. So this is equal to $500$.
So this let me $1855$ $x_i$ such that the sum of these $x$ is 0. And we have $0=742\cdot3-1113\cdot2$ so it means again $742$ times $3$ and $1113$ times $-2$.
All this give : $742+167=909$ times $3$, $1113$ times $-2$ and $2$ times $-0,5$.
We have : $3*909-2*1113-0,5*2=500$.

And this gives me : $909*3^4+1113*2^4+2*0,5^4=91437.125$
I think i got a wrong result. Could anyone gives me some help please ?

Comment: You could try Lagrange multiplicators. Or a variation argument.

Comment: It's not clear if these are meant to be integer or arbitrary reals.  In any case, taking $909$ $(3)'s$, $1113$ $(-2)'s$, $1$ $(1)$,  and $1$ $(0)$ yields $91438$. Not sure that's optimal though.

Comment: @lulu, can't you trade a $-2$, a $1$, and a $0$ for a $3$ and a pair of $-2$s to increase your sum? Ah, I think your $1(1)$ should be $1(-1)$ to get the sum $500$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Right,  sorry for the typo.

Comment: Then trade in $-2,-1,0$ for $-2,-2,1$.

Comment: You may look at Krein-Milman theorem and notice that the function $f(x_1,\cdots,x_{2024})=x_1^4+\cdots+x_{2024}^4$ is convex. So the maximum must be attained on the boundary of the convex $\{(x_1,\cdots,x_{2024})\in [-2,3]^{2024}:x_1+\cdots+x_{2024}=500\}$.

Comment: So if i apply all this i think we can have $909$ $(3)'$, $1114$ $(-2)$'s and $1$ $(1)$, we have $909*3^4+1114*2^4+1*1^4=91454$ but could anyone explain how to PROVE that this is the maximal value ?

Comment: Step One: prove that if you're using two numbers $a$, $b$, with $-2<a<b<3$ then you can increase the sum by moving $a$ and $b$ away from each other.